# jQuery - Animating transform works only one time on the same element

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

Whenever I try to animate CSS transform(scale) with jquery, it works only the first time, after the first animation when I try to animate the same element again it just skips to the end.

HTML

```
<button class="button_v1">animate v1</button>
<div class="animate_v1"></div>
```

SCSS

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: cyan;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

    &.animate_v1 {
        -moz-transform: scale(0, 1);
        -webkit-transform: scale(0, 1);
        -o-transform: scale(0, 1);
        -ms-transform: scale(0, 1);
        transform: scale(0, 1);
    }
}
```

jQuery

```
var toggle_v1 = false;
$('.button_v1').click(function(e) {
    if(toggle_v1) {
        $('.animate_v1').stop().animate({ scale: 100 }, { 
            step: function(now, fx) {
                $(this).css('transform', 'scale('+ (100-now)/100 +', 1)'); 
            },
            duration: 300,
        });
    }
    else {
        $('.animate_v1').stop().animate({ scale: 100 }, { 
            step: function(now, fx) {
                $(this).css('transform', 'scale('+ now/100 +', 1)'); 
            },
            duration: 300,
        });
    }
    toggle_v1 = !toggle_v1;
});
```

Here's a more detailed example that shows the behaviour **(fixed):** https://jsfiddle.net/4q76xz1u/51/

I've been on the struggle bus, trying to fix it for like 4 hours now, and I'm slowly becoming hopeless.

What the hell do I do next? Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"it works only the first time, after the first animation when I try to animate it again it just skips to the end."_ Cannot reproduce. `javascript`, `css` at Question returns expected result

Comment: Yes, it works, but only if you animate it once. If you animate the same element twice it won't work (you can try it on the jsfiddle link).

Comment: Same element is animated at each click of button at jsfiddle, here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var toggle_v1 = false;
$('.button_v1').click(function(e) {
    if(toggle_v1) {
        $('.animate_v1').stop().animate({ scale: 0 }, { 
            step: function(now, fx) {
                $(this).css('transform', 'scale('+ now/100 +', 1)'); 
            },
            duration: 300,
        });
    }
    else {
        $('.animate_v1').stop().animate({ scale: 100 }, { 
            step: function(now, fx) {
                $(this).css('transform', 'scale('+ now/100 +', 1)'); 
            },
            duration: 300,
        });
    }
    toggle_v1 = !toggle_v1;
});
```

Got the first one working but the second isn't co-oporating

Comment: I see what you did there, it's working now, thank's a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I always use background-COLOR: cyan; I don't think that is the problem  but still.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it with

```
-webkit-transition: all ease-in-out .5s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .5s;
-o-transition: all ease-in-out .5s, box-shadow ease-in-out .5s;
transition: all ease-in-out .5s, box-shadow ease-in-out .5s;
```

to the main div, and the you can change the max-widht property, and it will be animate.

For example:

```
<style>
.main {
    -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out .5s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .5s;
    -o-transition: all ease-in-out .5s, box-shadow ease-in-out .5s;
    transition: all ease-in-out .5s, box-shadow ease-in-out .5s;
    width: 300px;
    max-width: 20px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
}
.main:hover {
    max-width: 200px;
}

</style>
<div class="main"></div>
```

You can do it with jquery or javascript..

$(".main").css("max-width", "200px");

For example: https://jsfiddle.net/Balaz98/fa3jbwb4/

I hope it can solve your problem..